# Tiff headers and bit-order

Tags: tiff

> Bytes 0-1: The byte order used within the file. Legal values are: 
>   “II” (4949.H) 
>   “MM”(4D4D.H) 
>   In the “II” format, byte order is always from the least significant byte to the most 
>   significant byte, for both 16-bit and 32-bit integers This is called little-endian byte 
>   order. In the “MM” format, byte order is always from most significant to least 
>   significant, for both 16-bit and 32-bit integers. This is called big-endian byte 
>   order.
>
> Bytes 2-3 An arbitrary but carefully chosen number (42) that further identifies the file as a 
>   TIFF file. 
>   The byte order depends on the value of Bytes 0-1.
>
> Bytes 4-7 The offset (in bytes) of the first IFD. The directory may be at any location in the 
>   file after the header but must begin on a word boundary. In particular, an Image 
>   File Directory may follow the image data it describes. Readers must follow the 
>   pointers wherever they may lead. 
>   The term byte offset is always used in this document to refer to a location with 
>   respect to the beginning of the TIFF file. The first byte of the file has an offset of 
>   0.

Am I correct in understanding that bytes 0-1 represent two 8-bit values, bytes 2-3 are a 16-number, and that bytes 4-7 are a 32-bit number?

Comment: Hi Hatorade - are the questions you are asking homework questions? Can you consolidate all questions you have asked vis-a-vis TIFF into a single question thread?

Comment: no, they are not homework. they are all on the same project though. and i've been told before to separate questions into unique questions rather than place multiple questions in the same posting.

Comment: Alright then, good luck in getting answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Bytes 0-1 represent two 8-bit values>

   - yes
   - bytes 2-3 are a 16-number?
   - Yes, it should be a 16-value that represents `42` in the order expected from the first two bytes
   - and, that bytes 4-7 are a 32-bit number
   - yes. Its value is to be interpreted correctly based on the endian-ness confirmed earlier.

The little-endian start,

```
0x49 0x49 0x2A 0x00 0x67 0x45 0x23 0x01 ...
---- ---- --------- -------------------
```

Can be represented in big-endian as,

```
0x4D 0x4D 0x00 0x2A 0x01 0x23 0x45 0x67 ...
---- ---- --------- -------------------
```

Where the word has value `19088743`.

Maybe [this code reference](http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_Codes/Read_Wirte_Create_Tiff_File_VC_Source_Code_Example.htm) will help you get it better.
Also, note my earlier comment on byte-sequences and words [in the other answer](https://superuser.com/questions/37055/trouble-understanding-endianess/37066#37066)...